# Ubuntu 16.04: touchpad and mouse stopped working, Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, mouse-pointer

After installing recent updates, my touchpad and mouse stopped working on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro. Touchscreen and keyboard work fine. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue will be much appreciated.